# "Unable to get Terminal size" error in a perl script

Tags: perl, terminal

I installed Visual Studio Code (Vrs 1.4.0) in my Windows 10 device.

I have a perl script that starts with this lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# OK, recuerda que comilla simple no interpreta los caracteres reservados.
# calcula apariciones de numeros para sorteos segun solicitud
$txt1 = "De que sorteo quieres calcular corazonada?\n"; 
...
```

When I try to run it, I receive this error:

> Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.

There are some other warning messages, but this is the error that stops the script.

How do I need to fix this?

Comment: 1) What you posted doesn't use Term::ReadLine. The error didn't come from the code you posted. 2) Are you running the program from within a terminal/console? If not, then yeah, it's going to be hard to get the terminal size. Perhaps you should only use `readline` when connected to a terminal/console...

Comment: Ok – ikegami- my knowledge of perl is very short, I'm going to read about this "Term;;ReadLine" to see what are you talking about. Thanks- (I'm using the "run" option in VSC, Perhaps I need open a terminal and try to test there)

Answer (score 1):

The error message you quoted tells you one simple way to work around it:

```
set LINES=40
set COLUMNS=80
```

Reference: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1059438